# XDocument not loading properly

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

I've been making a clone of Cookie Clicker. To save the game, I save it to XML format. Example:

```
<save>
  <cookies>1</cookies>
  <clickers>0</clickers>
  <workers>0</workers>
  <factories>0</factories>
  <slavecountries>0</slavecountries>
  <worlds>0</worlds>
  <planets>0</planets>
  <universes>0</universes>
  <realities>0</realities>
</save>
```

Loading code:

```
    var doc = XDocument.Parse(save);
    var data = from item in doc.Root.Descendants("save")
        select new
        {
            cookies = item.Element("cookies").Value,
            clickers = item.Element("clickers").Value,
            workers = item.Element("workers").Value,
            factories = item.Element("factories").Value,
            slavecountries = item.Element("slavecountries").Value,
            worlds = item.Element("worlds").Value,
            planets = item.Element("planets").Value,
            universes = item.Element("universes").Value,
            realities = item.Element("realities").Value
        };
    Variables.Cookies = long.Parse(data.FirstOrDefault().cookies);
    Variables.Clickers = long.Parse(data.FirstOrDefault().clickers);
    Variables.Workers = long.Parse(data.FirstOrDefault().workers);
    Variables.Factories = long.Parse(data.FirstOrDefault().factories);
    Variables.SlaveCountries = long.Parse(data.FirstOrDefault().slavecountries);
    Variables.Worlds = long.Parse(data.FirstOrDefault().worlds);
    Variables.Planets = long.Parse(data.FirstOrDefault().planets);
    Variables.Universes = long.Parse(data.FirstOrDefault().universes);
    Variables.Realities = long.Parse(data.FirstOrDefault().realities);
```

I get an exception when I try to set my variables to the data (`Variables.Cookies = long.Parse(data.FirstOrDefault().cookies);`). Why isn't it loading properly?

Comment: Your `doc.Root` is the `save`-Element and that element has no descendants of type `save` what results in an empty enumeration and the call `FirstOrDefault()` will return `null` what results in your Exception

Comment: Did you try to inspect the "data" variable with a breakpoint? What's in that object? Can you paste the stack trace?

Comment: also, doing this like that means your xml is re-evaluated each time you call `.FirstOrDefault()`, which is pretty nasty. Do `var data = from [...]}.FirstOrDefault()`, and simply call `data.cookies`, `data.clickers`, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `Root` from query and use directly `doc.Descendants("save")` as shown in below

```
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"D:\test.xml");
    var data = from item in doc.Descendants("save")
               select new
               {
                   cookies = item.Element("cookies").Value,
                   clickers = item.Element("clickers").Value,
                   workers = item.Element("workers").Value,
                   factories = item.Element("factories").Value,
                   slavecountries = item.Element("slavecountries").Value,
                   worlds = item.Element("worlds").Value,
                   planets = item.Element("planets").Value,
                   universes = item.Element("universes").Value,
                   realities = item.Element("realities").Value
               };

    foreach (var item in data)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring error conditions for now (ie element names not matching, missing elements), the following will work for you. The original LINQ isn't necessary as far as I can see, as you only have one root element.

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(save);
var cookies = doc.Root.Element("cookies").Value;
var clickers = doc.Root.Element("clickers").Value;
var workers = doc.Root.Element("workers").Value;
var factories = doc.Root.Element("factories").Value;
var slavecountries = doc.Root.Element("slavecountries").Value;
var worlds = doc.Root.Element("worlds").Value;
var planets = doc.Root.Element("planets").Value;
var universes = doc.Root.Element("universes").Value;
var realities = doc.Root.Element("realities").Value;
```

I'll leave it as an exercise for you to put these into your `Variables` object. But in that section, bear in mind you may want to deal with the case where the numbers entered aren't valid also, i.e. use `long.TryParse`

Comment: `Variables` isn't an object, but a static class ;)  And I also use try-catch blocks when using the method loading the save file itself.

Comment: cool - the above will work then, no need for LINQ in this case.

Answer (score 1):

First, the root is `<Save>` so you are iterating all `<save>` elements of the root(`Root.Descendants("save")`), which  is empty set i.e. there is no `<save><save></save></save>` element.

Second, `Descendants` will iterate over all child elements, so `Element` is loading an element of the node in question, which does not exist.

The code you are looking for is:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(save);
var root = doc.Root;
Variables.Cookies = long.Parse(root.Element("cookies").Value);
Variables.clickers = long.Parse(root.Element("clickers").Value);
etc..
```